# cookies set double quote for email params

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, httpcookie

I need to pass get params and stored those params in cookies.

I have passed params like below

```
localhost:3030/free-trial?firstName=hardik&lastName=patel&email=hrpatel%40test-info.com
```

I have written code to set this on cookie

But in Cookie It is set like below for email param.

```
"hrpatel@test-info.com"
```

can Anyone tell me why this extra double Quotes are appended in my browser cookie?

Any help is appriciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Where's the code that sets the cookie?

Comment: I have set like CookieUtils.addCookie(response: response, request: request, name: it, value: params[it], domain:grailsApplication.config.cookieDomain, path: "/")